# Gitbook to PDF - Tables columns are getting cut-off

Tags: gitbook

When generating a pdf(and also in the website), columns are getting cut-off. This is possible to fix with css in the website but not in PDF.
Is there any solution to this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

book.json file update paperSize is a3

```
"pdf": {
    "pageNumbers": true,
    "fontSize": 12,
    "paperSize": "a3",
    "margin": {
        "right": 62,
        "left": 62,
        "top": 36,
        "bottom": 36
    },
    "headerTemplate": null,
    "footerTemplate": null
}
```